# cpp: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: cc

i face with following error when i build roms model by ./build.bash command. appeared error is

```
cpp: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
```

i use `yum install gcc-c++` but it replied that package gcc-c++-4.6.3-2fc16.i686 already installed . but i get nothing after typing `whereis cc1`.then i find cc1 in /usr/libexec/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.6.3. therefore i navigate to /usr/bin and create link by ln -s cc cc1. after that by typing `whereis cc1` it replied:/usr/bin/cc1
again by typing ./build.bash it reply:

```
cc1:error:unrecognized command line option '-quiet'
```

would you please tell me how i can sort out this problem. 
cheers 
fereshte